# How to change ownership of apps on AppStore and GooglePlay

Tags: android, ios, swift, google-play, app-store

I have a few questions to which I cant seem to find answer regarding AppStore and GooglePlay. 
So here is the situation. My client currently has an app in both stores developed and maintained by a developer agency (lets call them XXX).
Now my company is about to build new apps for our client and I am struggling to find answer to those question:

1) Can the ownership of the current apps be changed from XXX to us? So the current app becomes listed under our developer account.

2) If so, once ownership is changed can we replace the current apps with our new one - so we retain star ratings, reviews etc. Potentially list the new app as an UPDATE rather then a brand new one.

3) If both of the above are possible and we change the current apps with new ones - are people that have AUTO-UPDATE on, going to receive the new app without having to re-download it (essentially replacing the old one with new).

Altogether we want to avoid making users having to re-download apps. You can consider that we will receive all the help and support from XXX to do that. New apps will be built on Swift if that changes anything.

Please let me know

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

With AppleStore I knew you are able to change the app ownership with some restrictions.
Check this [Link](https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account) for the procedure.

With Google Play Console basically I never did it. 
But I found [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en) on a Play Console Help.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @emilBudev I would strongly suggest that your client gets their own Apple developer program membership and has the app transferred to that. They can then make you a member of that program for the purposes of developing the new release.  This way if they want to use another development company in the future they won't have to go through the process of transferring from your account. Also it makes review with company branding easier. Apple can reject an app if the branding doesn't match the developer name.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answers. What about the auto-update? If I manage to change ownership, you reckon that replacing the app will auto-update it for users? I assume that as it will be under same account, same app id all that.

Comment: @EmilBudev I don't know, I'm supposing its like a normal update and the app keeps the App Store page.